# Does output redirection write stdout and stderr info in order?

Tags: linux, shell, io-redirection

I wrote a program `capture` which output stdout message as well as stderr message (i.e, printf(), fprintf(stderr,..))

and I want the print information to be displayed on terminal as well as saved into log file.

```
  ./capture 2>&1|tee log
```

but I see that the stdout and stderr messages seem not to be in order in the log file.

does output redirection write stdout and stderr info in order?
if not, what can I do to make them in order?

Answer (score 0):

Output redirection as it is keeps the order of your `write()` calls. Redirection only changes the file descriptor structure in the kernel held for the process, copying the value from under `fd1` into `fd2`.

Your problem is that `*printf()` buffers the output batching some `write()` calls. Normally no buffering for `stderr` and `line-buffering` for `stdout` is used. But as you redirect it into a pipe, it switches to `block` buffering for `stdout`, delaying the output (See `man stdout`). Turn the buffering mode to line manually with `setlinebuf(stdout);` at the beginning, or use `fflush(stdout);` after every `*printf()`. Or just use raw `write()` calls. You can read about this in `man setlinebuf`.

In bash actually you can do that redirection with `|&` as well. Check out `man bash` about `Pipelines`.